# I am trying to design spark dataframe from column values to column name from existing spark dataframe but i am not getting required output for long?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have dataframe like below -

```
tagname    tagvalue            filename
starttime  2022-08-04 10:00:00 abc
endtime    2022-08-04 10:20:00 abc
startime   2022-08-04 10:10:00 xyz
endtime    2022-08-04 10:50:00 xyz
```

i want this in below format

```
filename starttime           endtime
abc      2022-08-04 10:00:00 2022-08-04 10:20:00
xyz      2022-08-04 10:10:00 2022-08-04 10:50:00
```

please help? i tried many ways it did not work

Comment: Is it possible to format your DataFrame examples so it's clear to see headers and values in a columns? Otherwise it's difficult to understand the problem and suggest a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we can group by `filename` and collect_set on `tagvalue`, renaming it as `data`.

```
.groupBy("filename").agg(collect_set(col("tagvalue")).as("data"))
```

**EDIT:**

After collecting, sort by

```
.withColumn("data", array_sort(col("data")))
```

Then, we create two columns, `starttime` and `endttime` as below:

```
  .withColumn("starttime", col("data").getItem(0))
  .withColumn("endtime", col("data").getItem(1))
```

We finally drop `data`, our final result:

```
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+
|filename|starttime          |endtime            |
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+
|xyz     |2022-08-04 10:10:00|2022-08-04 10:50:00|
|abc     |2022-08-04 10:00:00|2022-08-04 10:20:00|
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

which is what you need, good luck (you can also order by filename asc, but I did not do that)!

Comment: Thanks vilalabinot... but this is non deterministic. As somtimes endtime entry goes to starttime which should not happen.

Comment: I edited the answer, I added a sort on the array which should fix that. I did not anticipate that, sorry